# How can I ensure a repeatable migration is applied after a certain fixed-version migration?

Tags: flyway

The [Flyway documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/repeatable) contains this simple example of a repeatable migration:

```
-- R__Blue_cars.sql

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW blue_cars AS SELECT id, license_plate FROM cars WHERE color='blue';
```

However, this migration presumably depends on a previous fixed-version migration that creates the `cars` table (let's call it `V1__Create_Cars_Table.sql`).

How can I ensure the repeatable migration is run after this fixed-version migration when deploying to a new database? Or does Flyway apply the fixed-version migrations first and the repeatable ones after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioned migrations are applied before repeatable ones.